# Flask WTF localization with Babel

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, python-babel

I've used Flask Babel and have localized my project, but I have a problem with WTF forms, I can't translate the fields shown when field is empty. Any help?

This is working:

```
return jsonify({'error': gettext('Incorrect Data')}), 406
```

but when dealing with the Form class, Babel doesn't extract the field. like this:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = TextField(gettext(u'Username'), validators=[validators.Required()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[validators.Required()])
```

I've tried both with/without the 'u' option

Comment: Can you post an example of what is working wrong?

Comment: Yes. I edited my post. Is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages for validator `Required` are set via `Required(message=error_message)`, translate them with babel as well. Refer to [WTForms documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html) for more details.

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = TextField(gettext(u'Username'), validators=[validators.Required(message='Validation failed for username')])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[validators.Required(message='Validation failed for password')])
```

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I don't want to translate the messages. I want to translate the fields' placeholders. The items that are shown when the field is empty

Comment: In my case for localization I translate placeholders in python script, and send translated messages to html form, where use them in the following way:

`{{form.name(placeholder=ui.get('login'))}}`

where `form.name` is `wtforms.fields.StringField`, and `ui` is a dictionary with translated placeholders.

Comment: Not what I was expecting but it does the trick for me. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain the ui dictionary? How do you define it? Where?

Comment: This is a simple dictionary, where I store my localized messages. It looks like:

`ui = {'login': 'Ім’я користувача', 'password': 'Пароль'}`

I prefer such type of localizing my projects.

Answer (score 0):

try with `lazy_gettext('')`.

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = TextField(lazy_gettext(u'Username'), validators=[validators.Required()])
```

in **HTML**:

```
{{form.username.label (class="form-control-label") }}
```